# Getting bad gateway 502 error in nGinx server using Kubernates cluster

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, kubernetes

I am getting a error while loading my one of microservices in node nGnix server using Kubernates cluster.

Here is the error:

```
110#110: *20 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 61.xxx.221.179, server: dev.XXXXX.in, request: "GET /api/ticket/getTicketDetails HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://100.96.x.xxx:3001/api/ticket/getTicketDetails", host: "dev.XXXX.in"
```

Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Please do,

> kubectl exec -it meta_data_name -- /bin/bash
>
> curl http://100.96.x.xxx:3001/api/ticket/getTicketDetails

Mostly, this will fail as the upstream might not be running or there is no connectivity to it.

Check for logs inside the nodeJs micro-service to find if it is termination on incoming requests due to some error.